# Caliburn.Micro: Could not locate the source file SequentialResult.cs

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, coroutine

Trying to use the IResult Coroutines in Caliburn.Micro throws this strange exception, am I doing something wrong or is the Framework broken?

This happens on a `yield return result` where `result` is a custom `IResult` class.

```
Locating source for 'C:\Projects\Blue Spire\Caliburn.Micro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\SequentialResult.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {a2 6e ce dd c5 8c b3 ec 9c 21 b7 9 29 24 e7 a5}
The file 'C:\Projects\Blue Spire\Caliburn.Micro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\SequentialResult.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'C:\Projects\Blue Spire\Caliburn.Micro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\SequentialResult.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'C:\Projects\Blue Spire\Caliburn.Micro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\SequentialResult.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: C:\Projects\Blue Spire\Caliburn.Micro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\SequentialResult.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'C:\Projects\Blue Spire\Caliburn.Micro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\SequentialResult.cs'
```

**EDIT**

I was asked for some code. I'm still working on this but I was trying to get this to run. I was basically trying to get a Paging mechanism and CM IResult to work together to call a WCF service.

```
public class PagedRequestManager<T>: IResult where T : IPagedRequest
{
    public delegate IAsyncResult BeginRequestDelegate<T>(T request, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    public delegate IPagedResponse EndRequestDelegate(IAsyncResult result);

    private BeginRequestDelegate<T> _beginRequest;
    private EndRequestDelegate _endRequest;
    private T _request;

    public IPagedResponse Response { get; private set; }

    public PagedRequestManager(BeginRequestDelegate<T> beginRequest, EndRequestDelegate endRequest, T request)
    {
        _beginRequest = beginRequest;
        _endRequest = endRequest;
        _request = request;
    }

    public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed;

    public void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
    {
        _beginRequest(_request, PagedCallback, null);
    }

    private void PagedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Response = _endRequest(result);
        OnCompleted();
    }

    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        var handler = Completed;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs());
        }
    }
}


public interface IPagedRequest
{
    PageContext PageInfo { get; set; }
}


public interface IPagedResponse
{
    PageContext PageInfo { get; }
    IEnumerable Result { get; }
}
```

and usage:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> TestWCF()
{
    var result = new PagedRequestManager<GetItemsRequest>(client.BeginGetItems, client.EndGetItems, new GetItemsRequest() { PageInfo = new PageContext() { Skip = 0, Take = 10 } });
    yield return result;
}
```

While we are at it perhaps someone would like to mention whether this is a good solution at all. I'm not really sure how to use the IResult mechanism of CM and what the best way would be to push the things I get from each WCF call into the list.

Comment: Are you adding reference to caliburn.micro manually? Or using the Nuget package manager? If manually, remove the references and try installing with Nuget; rebuild and see if that helps.

Comment: Which CM version are you using, and in which context (WPF, SL, WP7, Metro)?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson - in response to the answer you deleted, caliburn.micro's WPF assembly references the caliburn.micro SilverLight assembly.

Comment: @MetroSmurf I realized that soon afterwards, I was too quick with the Answer button... Thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Comment: The following [discussion](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/275242) took place in the Caliburn Micro forum a year or so ago. It is not the exact same error, but maybe it can give some clues.

Comment: Could you post some of your code for facilitated investigation, because the above message only seems to be a result of the debugger not finding source code when trying to indicate where the error appears.

Comment: I used NuGet to install, got version 1.3.1 and am using it in a WPF project. I was certain there was something missing that's why I didn't have any code. But it could be my code that's causing this?

Comment: I have also installed from NuGet and used in WPF project, but have not run into your error message. I do however get similar error screens when I have coded insufficiently, but there has then also been a preceding error message. Maybe you can provide a screen dump of your error report?

Comment: Added some code for you to look at.

Comment: Ok figured something out. The reason the exception is happening inside the Caliburn Micro code is because that's where he is running the Execute method. So it is my code that is broken not the Caliburn Micro one. So the problem is totally unrelated to what I though initially.

Comment: @IngóVals Did you eventually manage to solve this? I could not detect any obvious issues with the code you provided.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Yes I did. I got confused and thought because the exception was happening inside Caliburn.Micro code it had to be something broken there. This was of course my own code that was being run inside the CM framework. Rookie mistake really. First thing in debugging is locate the source of the problem isn't.